# Why won't animate package work?

Tags: animate

I'd like to play a bit with the animate package but even the absolutely minimal example below gives me an error message :

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Here is the beginning of the log file

```
! Undefined control sequence. l.3 \ExplSyntaxOn The control sequence
at the end of the top line of your error message was never 
\def'ed. If you have misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
l.4 \bool
_if:nTF{
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
$
l.4 \bool_
if:nTF{
I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.4 \bool_
if:nTF{
You're in trouble here. Try typing <return> to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type X <return> to quit.
LaTeX Font Info: External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font) <7> on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: External font `cmex10' loaded for size
```

Thanks for any tips !

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I cannot reproduce your problem. Your tex file compiles successfully with my own TeX Live 2021 as well as at overleaf.com.

Comment: It also compiles fine in my computer. I use MiKTeX under Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **Wild guess:** There is a problem with the version of packages, e. g. one package that is needed by `animate` was updated and is now incompatible.
- **Proposal 1:** Update your LaTeX installation, see [How do I update my TeX distribution?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437). If that does not work, then try again in one week or so.
- **Proposal 2:** Use [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/) in the meantime in order to gain experience with the *awesome* `animate` package.

Comment: Thanks, updating everything in my MikTeX concole did the trick. I'm now looking at a sine wave drawing itself inside a pdf and it is indeed awesome :)